# Sitecore 9.3 SIA installation fails in part 2

Tags: installation, sitecore, microsoft-web-deploy, sitecore9

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.3 using SIA on my local instance. Everything works fine with the prerequisites, solr, gets to actually installing Sitecore, but when getting to the part 2 of the installation, I get the following error:

> [---------------------- SPE_InstallWDP : WebDeploy ---------------------------]
> [WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
> Error: Unrecognized argument '"-SetParam:Name="Core'. All arguments must begin with "-".
> Error count: 1.
>
> Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
> returned a non-zero exit code - (-1) [TIME] 00:00:03 Command
> C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a
> non-zero exit code - (-1)

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? I have the **msdeploy.exe** at the mentioned location. I  believe I searched for days and no luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The cause was the MSSQL Admin Password that contained a quote. In these cases , generally check if the parameters passed to SIA contain unfavorable characters.